# Why the method createPlatformApplication(platformApplicationRequest) is undefined?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

```
private CreatePlatformApplicationResult createPlatformApplication(
            String applicationName, Platform platform, String principal,
            String credential) {

        CreatePlatformApplicationRequest platformApplicationRequest = new CreatePlatformApplicationRequest();
        Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
        attributes.put("PlatformPrincipal", principal);
        attributes.put("PlatformCredential", credential);
        platformApplicationRequest.setAttributes(attributes);
        platformApplicationRequest.setName(applicationName);
        platformApplicationRequest.setPlatform(platform.name());
        return snsClient.createPlatformApplication(platformApplicationRequest);
}

private CreatePlatformEndpointResult createPlatformEndpoint(
            Platform platform, String customData, String platformToken,
            String applicationArn) {
        CreatePlatformEndpointRequest platformEndpointRequest = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
        platformEndpointRequest.setCustomUserData(customData);
        String token = platformToken;
        String userId = null;
        if (platform == Platform.BAIDU) {
            String[] tokenBits = platformToken.split("\\|");
            token = tokenBits[0];
            userId = tokenBits[1];
            Map<String, String> endpointAttributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
            endpointAttributes.put("UserId", userId);
            endpointAttributes.put("ChannelId", token);
            platformEndpointRequest.setAttributes(endpointAttributes);
        }
        platformEndpointRequest.setToken(token);
        platformEndpointRequest.setPlatformApplicationArn(applicationArn);
        return snsClient.createPlatformEndpoint(platformEndpointRequest);
        }

        private void deletePlatformApplication(String applicationArn) {
        DeletePlatformApplicationRequest request = new DeletePlatformApplicationRequest();
        request.setPlatformApplicationArn(applicationArn);
        snsClient.deletePlatformApplication(request);
        }

        private PublishResult publish(String endpointArn, Platform platform,
            Map<Platform, Map<String, MessageAttributeValue>> attributesMap,String messageToSend) {
        PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest();
        Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> notificationAttributes =        
        getValidNotificationAttributes(attributesMap
                .get(platform));
        if (notificationAttributes != null && !notificationAttributes.isEmpty()) {
            publishRequest.setMessageAttributes(notificationAttributes);
        }
        publishRequest.setMessageStructure("json");
        // If the message attributes are not set in the requisite method,
        // notification is sent with default attributes
        String message = getPlatformSampleMessage(platform,messageToSend);
        Map<String, String> messageMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        messageMap.put(platform.name(), message);
        message = SampleMessageGenerator.jsonify(messageMap);
        // For direct publish to mobile end points, topicArn is not relevant.
        publishRequest.setTargetArn(endpointArn);

        // Display the message that will be sent to the endpoint/
        System.out.println("{Message Body: " + message + "}");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("{Message Attributes: ");
        for (Map.Entry<String, MessageAttributeValue> entry : notificationAttributes
                .entrySet()) {
            builder.append("(\"" + entry.getKey() + "\": \""
                    + entry.getValue().getStringValue() + "\"),");
        }
        builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
        builder.append("}");
        System.out.println(builder.toString());

        publishRequest.setMessage(message);
        return snsClient.publish(publishRequest);
        }

        public void demoNotification(Platform platform, String principal,
            String credential, String platformToken, String applicationName,
            Map<Platform, Map<String, MessageAttributeValue>> attrsMap,String message) {
        // Create Platform Application. This corresponds to an app on a
        // platform.
        CreatePlatformApplicationResult platformApplicationResult = createPlatformApplication(
                applicationName, platform, principal, credential);
        System.out.println(platformApplicationResult);

        // The Platform Application Arn can be used to uniquely identify the
        // Platform Application.
        String platformApplicationArn = platformApplicationResult
                .getPlatformApplicationArn();

        // Create an Endpoint. This corresponds to an app on a device.
        CreatePlatformEndpointResult platformEndpointResult = createPlatformEndpoint(
                platform,
                "CustomData - Useful to store endpoint specific data",
                platformToken, platformApplicationArn);
        System.out.println(platformEndpointResult);

        // Publish a push notification to an Endpoint.
        PublishResult publishResult = publish(
                platformEndpointResult.getEndpointArn(), platform, attrsMap,message);
        System.out.println("Published! \n{MessageId="
                + publishResult.getMessageId() + "}");
        // Delete the Platform Application since we will no longer be using it.
        deletePlatformApplication(platformApplicationArn);
        }

        private String getPlatformSampleMessage(Platform platform,String messageToSend) {
        switch (platform) {
        case APNS:
            return SampleMessageGenerator.getSampleAppleMessage();
        case APNS_SANDBOX:
            return SampleMessageGenerator.getSampleAppleMessage();
        case GCM:
            return SampleMessageGenerator.getSampleAndroidMessage(messageToSend);
        case ADM:
            return SampleMessageGenerator.getSampleKindleMessage();
        case BAIDU:
            return SampleMessageGenerator.getSampleBaiduMessage();
        case WNS:
            return SampleMessageGenerator.getSampleWNSMessage();
        case MPNS:
            return SampleMessageGenerator.getSampleMPNSMessage();
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Platform not supported : "
                    + platform.name());
        }
        }

        public static Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> getValidNotificationAttributes(
            Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> notificationAttributes) {
        Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> validAttributes = new HashMap<String,   
        MessageAttributeValue>();

        if (notificationAttributes == null) return validAttributes;

        for (Map.Entry<String, MessageAttributeValue> entry : notificationAttributes
                .entrySet()) {
            if (!StringUtils.isBlank(entry.getValue().getStringValue())) {
                validAttributes.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        return validAttributes;
        }
        }
```

Comment: Probably because `snsClient` doesn't have a method with this signature, but without seeing the relevant code I can only guess.

Comment: Share your snsClient class code. Either the method is not there or it is not visible.

Comment: Um, guys, snsClient is Amazon's public SDK - the method in question is documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient.html#createPlatformApplication(com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.CreatePlatformApplicationRequest))

Comment: I'm assuming you double checked your code imports to make sure these are both coming from the SNS package, and are using the latest version of the SDK. Your question implies you're getting a compile error in your first method - can you be specific to the exact error message? It would also be useful to post an entire class containing only the relevant code that is causing problems - there's a lot of extra stuff here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AmazonSNSClientWrapper {

    private final AmazonSNS snsClient;

    public AmazonSNSClientWrapper(AmazonSNS client) {
        this.snsClient = client;
    }

    private CreatePlatformApplicationResult createPlatformApplication(
            String applicationName, Platform platform, String principal,
            String credential) {
        CreatePlatformApplicationRequest platformApplicationRequest = new CreatePlatformApplicationRequest();
        Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
        attributes.put("PlatformPrincipal", principal);
        attributes.put("PlatformCredential", credential);
        platformApplicationRequest.setAttributes(attributes);
        platformApplicationRequest.setName(applicationName);
        platformApplicationRequest.setPlatform(platform.name());
        return snsClient.createPlatformApplication(platformApplicationRequest);
    }

    private CreatePlatformEndpointResult createPlatformEndpoint(
            Platform platform, String customData, String platformToken,
            String applicationArn) {
        CreatePlatformEndpointRequest platformEndpointRequest = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
        platformEndpointRequest.setCustomUserData(customData);
        String token = platformToken;
        String userId = null;
        if (platform == Platform.BAIDU) {
            String[] tokenBits = platformToken.split("\\|");
            token = tokenBits[0];
            userId = tokenBits[1];
            Map<String, String> endpointAttributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
            endpointAttributes.put("UserId", userId);
            endpointAttributes.put("ChannelId", token);
            platformEndpointRequest.setAttributes(endpointAttributes);
        }
        platformEndpointRequest.setToken(token);
        platformEndpointRequest.setPlatformApplicationArn(applicationArn);
        return snsClient.createPlatformEndpoint(platformEndpointRequest);
    }

    private void deletePlatformApplication(String applicationArn) {
        DeletePlatformApplicationRequest request = new DeletePlatformApplicationRequest();
        request.setPlatformApplicationArn(applicationArn);
        snsClient.deletePlatformApplication(request);
    }

    private PublishResult publish(String endpointArn, Platform platform,
            Map<Platform, Map<String, MessageAttributeValue>> attributesMap, String msgText) {
        PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest();
        Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> notificationAttributes = getValidNotificationAttributes(attributesMap
                .get(platform));
        if (notificationAttributes != null && !notificationAttributes.isEmpty()) {
            publishRequest.setMessageAttributes(notificationAttributes);
        }
        publishRequest.setMessageStructure("json");
        // If the message attributes are not set in the requisite method,
        // notification is sent with default attributes
        String message = getPlatformMessage(platform, msgText);
        Map<String, String> messageMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        messageMap.put(platform.name(), message);
        message = MessageGenerator.jsonify(messageMap);
        // For direct publish to mobile end points, topicArn is not relevant.
        publishRequest.setTargetArn(endpointArn);

        // Display the message that will be sent to the endpoint/
        System.out.println("{Message Body: " + message + "}");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("{Message Attributes: ");
        for (Map.Entry<String, MessageAttributeValue> entry : notificationAttributes
                .entrySet()) {
            builder.append("(\"" + entry.getKey() + "\": \""
                    + entry.getValue().getStringValue() + "\"),");
        }
        builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
        builder.append("}");
        System.out.println(builder.toString());

        publishRequest.setMessage(message);
        return snsClient.publish(publishRequest);
    }

    public void NotificationWorker(Platform platform, String principal,
            String credential, String platformToken, String applicationName,
            Map<Platform, Map<String, MessageAttributeValue>> attrsMap, String message) {
        // Create Platform Application. This corresponds to an app on a
        // platform.
        CreatePlatformApplicationResult platformApplicationResult = createPlatformApplication(
                applicationName, platform, principal, credential);
        System.out.println(platformApplicationResult);

        // The Platform Application Arn can be used to uniquely identify the
        // Platform Application.
        String platformApplicationArn = platformApplicationResult
                .getPlatformApplicationArn();

        // Create an Endpoint. This corresponds to an app on a device.
        CreatePlatformEndpointResult platformEndpointResult = createPlatformEndpoint(
                platform,
                "CustomData - Useful to store endpoint specific data",
                platformToken, platformApplicationArn);
        System.out.println(platformEndpointResult);

        // Publish a push notification to an Endpoint.
        PublishResult publishResult = publish(
                platformEndpointResult.getEndpointArn(), platform, attrsMap,message);
        System.out.println("Published! \n{MessageId="
                + publishResult.getMessageId() + "}");
        // Delete the Platform Application since we will no longer be using it.
        deletePlatformApplication(platformApplicationArn);
    }

    private String getPlatformMessage(Platform platform) {
        switch (platform) {
        case APNS:
            return MessageGenerator.sendAppleMessage();
        case APNS_SANDBOX:
            return MessageGenerator.sendAppleMessage();
        case GCM:
            return MessageGenerator.getAndroidMessage();
        case ADM:
            return MessageGenerator.getKindleMessage();

        case WNS:
            return MessageGenerator.getWNSMessage();
        case MPNS:
            return MessageGenerator.getMPNSMessage();
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Platform not supported : "
                    + platform.name());
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> getValidNotificationAttributes(
            Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> notificationAttributes) {
        if (notificationAttributes != null) {

            Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> validAttributes = new HashMap<String, MessageAttributeValue>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, MessageAttributeValue> entry : notificationAttributes.entrySet()) {
                if (!StringUtils.isBlank(entry.getValue().getStringValue())) {
                    validAttributes.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            return validAttributes;
        } else {
            return new HashMap<String, MessageAttributeValue>();
        }
    }
}
```

I have changed the code according to my own requirements but it will work. Just check some of the method names because I have changed them. Hope it helps